# How to integrate Cody AI conversation bot with my Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, bots, integration

I am trying to integrate the Cody conversation bot with my Flutter app but I don't know how to do that since I am new with API's. I don't understand the elements of inside the API documentation of Cody AI. So please can anyone explain the steps for me in detailed. And if it is hard to do, is there any websites that offers the same service easily and with more simplified API integration?

Here's my trail at the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class Message {
  final String role;
  final String content;

  Message({required this.role, required this.content});
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  TextEditingController _inputController = TextEditingController();
  List<Message> _messages = [];

  final String apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY'; // Replace with your actual API key
  final String codyAiApiUrl = 'https://getcody.ai/api/v1/conversations';

  String? conversationId;

  Future<void> createConversation() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('$codyAiApiUrl'),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $apiKey', // Include your API key here
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          'name':
              'Sample Conversation', // Replace with your desired conversation name
          'bot_id': 'YourBotId', // Replace with your bot ID
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
        conversationId = responseData['data']['id'];
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _messages.add(Message(
            role: 'system',
            content: 'Error: ${response.statusCode} - ${response.reasonPhrase}',
          ));
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setState(() {
        _messages.add(Message(role: 'system', content: 'Error: $error'));
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> sendMessage(String text) async {
    if (conversationId == null) {
      await createConversation();
      if (conversationId == null) {
        // Conversation creation failed
        return;
      }
    }

    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('$codyAiApiUrl/$conversationId/messages'),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $apiKey', // Include your API key here
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          'role': 'user',
          'content': text,
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);

        setState(() {
          _messages.add(Message(
            role: responseData['role'],
            content: responseData['content'],
          ));
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _messages.add(Message(
            role: 'system',
            content: 'Error: ${response.statusCode} - ${response.reasonPhrase}',
          ));
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setState(() {
        _messages.add(Message(role: 'system', content: 'Error: $error'));
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('CodyAI Chat Example'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _messages.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final message = _messages[index];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      message.role,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(message.content),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _inputController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Type a message',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                    onPressed: () {
                      String text = _inputController.text;
                      sendMessage(text);
                      _inputController.clear();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your first step is to get this working in Postman or using the curl examples in their docs. Then update your question to show working requests (and their non-working Flutter attempted equivalents). If you don't understand their API, you need to contact the vendor for assistance.